# i cannot get images with querySelector method

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, css-selectors

Im trying to select all images in javascript var hers The Code

Html :

```
<div class="container">

<img src="Coca.jpg" class="imgg">
<img src="Water.jpg" class="imgg">
<img src="Tree.jpg" class="imgg">
<img src="Alien.jpg" class="imgg">

</div>
```

Css :

```
.container{
 margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
height: 480px;
width: 600px;
top: 23%;
left: 20%;
box-sizing: border-box;
background-color: red;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
align-content: flex-start;

}
img{

height: 160px;
width: 150px;


}
```

i try with query selector All It doesnt work :

```
var imges = document.querySelectorAll('.imgg')


imges.style.opacity=0;
```

I try with getElementsByTagName still doesnt work  :

```
var imges = document.getElementsByTagName('img');


imges.style.opacity=0;
```

i try with getElementsByClassName and the same issue

how to fix this ?

Comment: Pretty sure var images becomes an array that you have to step through to set the style on each image instance.

Answer (score -1):

document.querySelectorAll() returns a node list, not a single img element, so you can not do:

```
imges.style.opacity=0;
```

What you would have to do is iterate through that node list and apply desired styles to each element.

Comment: this is not an answer